# jq fails to set value with colon in jenkins pipeline

Tags: json, bash, jenkins, groovy, jq

My jenkins pipeline needs to manipulate **.updateApp.json** and set the name of an S3 bucket that contains **colons** as a value to the key `BucketARNUpdate`

What I tried up to now:

```
arn = "arn:aws:s3:::${PROJECT}-${STAGE}"
sh(script: 'jq  ".BucketARNUpdate=${arn}" .updateApp.json', returnStdout: true)
```

but this gives me

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

My second approach was using the --arg argument and I tried

`sh(script: 'jq --arg var \"${arn}\"  ".BucketARNUpdate=${var}" .updateApp.json', returnStdout: true)`

but this gives

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: var
```

I tried it both with and without escaping the `var` value. How do I get this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can only use the abbreviated form `.foo` if the key name is alphanumeric, it being understood that _ is counted as an alphabetic character here.

The basic form for referring to the value of a key named "KEY" is `.["KEY"]`, but recent versions of jq also allow `."KEY"`.

Using your first approach and ignoring whatever escapes may be required by jenkins, you could write:

```
 ".[\"BucketARNUpdate=${arn}\"]"
```

Your second approach, however, is perhaps safer.  Again ignoring whatever escapes may be required by jenkins, the invocation would look like this:

```
jq --arg var "${arn}"  '.["BucketARNUpdate=" + $var]' .updateApp.json
```